# Syntax Highlighting for Mathematica on a Blog

Tags: export, formatting, syntax-highlighting

Every once in a while I want to paste Mathematica code on my blog. When I do, I would like it to be somewhat readable, and it would be nice to have syntax highlighting. So far all my searches have turned up with nothing. There are plenty of ways to colorize pretty much every language known to man, except perhaps Mathematica code. See [this site](http://hilite.me/), for example. The closest I've gotten to that is using :TOhtml in vim, which is pretty awesome, but gives me a whole HTML file, with  and everything, and I'm not savvy enough to figure out exactly how to use it without destroying the rest of my post.

Comment: You might want to see [this](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting), by our very own [halirutan](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187).

Comment: Can you add details to you question, what blog-software you use? Are you having a server and full access to the data or do you use any *ready to use* installation?

Comment: I'm asking for blogger, so I don't really have full control over the server, but I can run remote formatting scripts and whatnot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you're writing a blog, then I assume you take some content management system like [Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) because otherwise a blog is maybe to hard to keep up-to-date in pure html. I have personal experience with Joomla and know, that code-highlighting as described below works great.

As mentioned by J.M. we have worked and tested hard to get a highlighter running for this site. What we did is to write a plug-in for the famous [google code prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). Please read [the discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8959323/1078614).

Therefore, the only thing you have to do is to setup google code prettify for your blog and add our language extension for *Mathematica* code [lang-mma.js](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting/raw/master/lang-mma.js) into the language files folder. Then you replace (you can of course adjust the colors for your site) the prettify stylesheet with [prettify-mma.css](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting/raw/master/prettify-mma.css).

Look around on this site. All code you see here is highlighted using this plug-in.

Comment: I will give all this a try. I knew a prettify plugin for Mathematica existed, but I had a lot of trouble finding it. For now, a quick an dirty solution I found works quite well is to use hilite.me and use OCaml as the language.

Comment: Actually, it turns out google code prettify supports Caml style languages. I ended up using <code class="lang-ml"></code> tags around my code and that did the trick.

Comment: @VladSeghete But you do realize that we (1) highlight **all** built-in functions and symbols, (2) support basic highlighting of patterns and (3) parse all styles of Mathematica numbers like ``1.23`3``??

Comment: definitely, using lang-ml is just a hack, but it doesn't require anything extra to install on the server. I'll have to look into how to get blogger to see the lang-mms file when I get a chance, but my main gripe (highlighting the comments) is fixed.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! It works GREAT on my wordpress site!

Comment: @Silvia You're welcome! I'm really glad this is used by others and not only for stackexchange and my own (currently offline) site.

Comment: It's so cool you did this. Before recalling that we already have a highlighter on this site, I tried really hard to construct a [crayon](http://aramk.com/projects/crayon-syntax-highlighter/) version for my blog with no success.. Mathematica indeed has a more complex syntax than C/java/...

Comment: @Silvia Why do I never see you in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica) or in our new [chatroom for our IntelliJ Mathematica plugin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8636/intellijidea-plugin-for-mathematica)? I think you're giving great answers and I think everyone would be glad if you'd be around from time to time.

Comment: Frankly, the main reason I rarely hang out in chat is that I'm afraid of not being able to catch up with other people -- because of my poor English..

Comment: Hi, Silvia, glad to know you're palying with something Jekyll [though seems update two years ago], Have you tried this plugin successfully in Jekyll site?@Silvia

Comment: @halirutan Hi, I found the loading sequence of JS is important. :)

Comment: @HyperGroups It would have been very unlikely that I could have helped you anyway. If you get google-prettify going then the Mathematica plugin should work too. If you don't, there isn't much I can do either. Glad you fixed it.