# Do any mainstream text editors support Wolfram Language syntax for highlighting?

Tags: syntax

[Syntax Highlighting for Mathematica on a Blog](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13737/syntax-highlighting-for-mathematica-on-a-blog)

There is the above, but I'm not terribly excited to install rogue packages.

For example on github, I share lots of *Mathematica* code.  I see no way to highlight syntax.  This may keep *Wolfram* down in the way of becoming a more often used and more robust programming language.

If the answer is, as I suspect,  *"no"*, perhaps a better question is *"why not?"*

Comment: Textmate has a bundle, which can also be used by Sublime (both are for the mac only as far as I know). However it doesn't include all the highlights I would like, like variable dependencies of functions, Modules and Blocks. It is technically open source and anyone can modify.

Comment: Sublime is actually multi-platform, and the most current fork of the bundle is [here](https://github.com/shadanan/mathematica-tmbundle)

Comment: Very cool.  Thank you.

Comment: Am I misreading this is only for OSX?

Comment: I was mistaken at first, Sublime is actually for  windows/linux and mac os x and you can use all the bundles from textmate with it.

Comment: Eclipse and Wolfram Workbench ?

Comment: There's also this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24556/open-source-intellijidea-plugin-to-support-mathematica-development

Comment: Vim comes with Mma syntax highlighting included.

Comment: If you use Notepad++ you may download Mma user-defined highlighting for it: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files http://imgur.com/cPDRhyX It's very simplistic but it's better than nothing.

Comment: emacs has at least one [`wolfram-mode`](https://github.com/kawabata/wolfram-mode/blob/master/wolfram-mode.el)